# Django Aggregations

Tags: django, django-models

Hi guys I want to create an invoice.For that I am  using  django aggregations for summing up the working hours.The code is like:

```
class ProjectTask(models.Model):

    project_info = models.ForeignKey(ProjectInvitation, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    scm_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    estimated_hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,
    decimal_places=2)
    percent_completed = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,
    decimal_places=2)
    worked_hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,
    decimal_places=2)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      worked_hours = self.estimated_hours * self.percent_completed 
      super(ProjectTask, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

total = ProjectTask.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('worked_hours'))
```

The problem is I am getting RuntimeError("App registry isn't ready yet.").Any idea how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with aggregation.

See the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#app-loading-changes